# Ruby on Rails - Take current Screen shot and save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to add a button to one of our web sites that will allow the user to file a bug with our bug tracking system.

One of the feature requests is that a screen cap of the page in question be sent along.

1. Is it possible ? (by using any gems)

Help to solve this.....

Comment: Take Screenshot of what exactly? User of your web apps screen? Your Screen? The way the browser Renders your page?  Do you want to do this in production? Testing?

Comment: @Doon Current screen of the web app, if any problem occurred, user click a send error mail button, with that mail, want to attach the current error page screenshot automatically

Comment: I am pretty sure you are going to have to have the user generate the screen shot(Maybe include instructions how to do it on different operating systems), and have them attach it. since an automatic way to do this would be a big security hole.  Would you need a screenshot, or could you just grab the entire DOM/InnerHTML of the part you want and save the generated source (just thinking out loud)

Answer (score 0):

[capybara-screenshot](https://github.com/mattheworiordan/capybara-screenshot) seems to be fairly popular.

I'm not familiar with any other Ruby Gems which offer this functionality by default but I know [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) plays nice with *rSpec* and enables screen capture functionality. As similar question may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821167/selenium-screenshots-using-rspec).

As well, [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/api.html#casper.captureSelector) offer this functionality too.